# Number of samples in transaction : 4, number of failing samples : 1 Getting this error message in my Response message

Tags: jmeter

Getting this error message in my Jmeter
Number of samples in transaction : 4, number of failing samples : 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is self-explanatory.

1. You have a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) in your Test Plan
2. You have 4 [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) under the Transaction Controller
3. One of samplers fails when you run your test causing the whole transaction to fail. Use a listener, i.e. [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to inspect request and response details and amend JMeter configuration to fix the error in your test (unless it is not the error in the application under test)